# lambda function logs are not properly logged in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am calling lambda function from home automation skill set.

When i test my lambda function using Test button, all expected logs are written in cloudwatch, but in real scenerio, there are no logs on cloudwatch. Can someone suggest why?

Comment: The logs are put inside a different streams. Can you check other newer streams?

Comment: last event time cloudwatch logstream is not getting updated and same logs were being generated on every request. My mistake.

Comment: Do you at least see the lines `START RequestId: XXX Version: XXX` and `END RequestId: XXX` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problems that some of my Lambda functions weren't logging anymore.
Make sure that the role you are using has permissions to write to cloudwatch. You could add [CloudWatchLogsFullAccess](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/role_cwl_full_access.html) policy or a more fine grained policy.

The policies that are generated on the fly are usually limited to a specific stream. If you invoke a different lambda it will have a different stream name so the permissions could mismatch.